# paint item in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, select, paint

Good morning.

I have a ListView of entries, where by selecting one of them shows the detail.
I need to change the background color of the entries that were accessed.
For that, I take the selected item and return a value intentificacion for 1.

```
lv_entries.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Entry entry = (Entry) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            entry.setSeleccion(1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListEntriesActivity.this,
                    EntryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Keys.ENTRY, entry);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Then I compare the adapter if the entry was accessed and change your background color:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Entry entry = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_entries,
                parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv_entry_title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_titulo);
        viewHolder.tv_entry_link = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_link);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if(entry.getSeleccion()==1){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.azul);
    }
    viewHolder.tv_entry_title.setText(entry.getTitle());
    viewHolder.tv_entry_link.setText(entry.getLink());


    return convertView;
}
```

the problem is that, in addition to paint the selected item, as I walk the list, will paint other items.

Someone could help me?

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your getView method, in order for your ListView to not use up a bunch of memory the ListView Recycles its items where of which by scrolling the list, will cause the backgrounds of the reused items to use the color you change to. So in order to stopp this from happening you should change getView to be:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   Entry entry = getItem(position);
   ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_entries,
            parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.tv_entry_title = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_titulo);
    viewHolder.tv_entry_link = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_list_link);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
if(entry.getSeleccion()==1){
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.azul);
}else{
   // Use your default color here
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
}
viewHolder.tv_entry_title.setText(entry.getTitle());
viewHolder.tv_entry_link.setText(entry.getLink());


return convertView;
}
```

Comment: No problem, this again is because list view items are recycled. So when getView was being called it was for a recycled item with the different background.